# How to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1\cdot8\cdot15\cdots(7n-6)}{7^nn!}$ converges or diverges with Ratio Test or nth Root Test

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

**EDIT:** as @saulspatz points out, I represented this entire thing incorrectly from the beginning so (**all I'm looking for at this point is the correct way to set up**) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1\cdot8\cdot15\cdots(7n-6)}{7^nn!}$

**EDIT:** I've received the answer I'm looking for, @saulspatz spelled it out for me nicely.

I have to prove whether $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1\cdot8\cdot15\cdots(7n-6)}{7^nn!}$$ converges or diverges (yes again, sorry to those who have to deal with my questions).

Comment: I don't understand the first step.  How do you get from 
$$\frac{1\cdot8\cdot15\cdots(7n-6)}{7^nn!}$$ to$$\frac{(7n-6)!}{7^nn!}?$$  In the first case, the numerator has only every seventh natural number up to $7n-6$, and in the second case, it has all of them.

Comment: @saulspatz I don't think I understand what you're saying, but this question is about an infinite series, so in the 'second case', it's still every 7th natural number up to $7n-6$ since the $\sum$ does every integer greater than or equal to 1... to infinity, same with the 1st case. If I didn't represent the series given, how should I have done it?

Comment: @saulspatz the reason I think it's the same thing is because if you picture yourself adding each term from $n=1,2,3,4...$ to infinity, each term is the exact same right?

Comment: @saulspatz I even answered a different question on my HW that instead of $1*3*4*5...(2n-1)!$ I replaced it with $(2n-1)!$ and it worked just fine. Not sure why this would be different. Again, these are all with infinite series though. Could've been a fluke

Comment: No, it isn't.  The $n=2$ term of the original series is $\frac{1\cdot8}{7^2\cdot2!}=\frac4{49}$.  This is a far cry from $\frac{(7\cdot2-6)!}{7^2\cdot2!}=\frac{8!}{98}=\frac{40320}{98}$

Comment: @saulspatz I see what you're saying now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to approach these, I think, is to write out a few of the terms to get a feeling of what you are looking at.  Here the first few terms are $$\frac17,\frac{8}{7^2\cdot2},\frac{8\cdot15}{7^3\cdot2\cdot3},\frac{8\cdot15\cdot22}{7^4\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4},\dots$$  Let's distribute the $7$'s, to make the terms in numerator and denominator more easily comparable.  We have $$\frac17,\frac{8}{7\cdot14}\frac{8\cdot15}{7\cdot14\cdot21},\frac{8\cdot15\cdot22}{7\cdot14\cdot21\cdot28},\dots$$
Rewrite them once more as
$$\frac17,\ \frac87\frac1{14},\ \frac87\frac{15}{14}\frac1{21},\ \frac87\frac{15}{14}\frac{22}{21}\frac1{28},\dots$$ and it's clear the terms are greater than those of the divergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{7n}$ and the series diverges.

Now to write it up, I would just prove that $$\frac{1\cdot8\cdot15\cdots(7n-6)}{7^nn!}\geq\frac1{7n}$$

Comment: Check this carefully.  It's past my bedtime, and I'm not thinking clearly at all.

Comment: My confirmation isn't going to be better than yours, it's past my bedtime too, and hey, I was the one who thought the numerator was the same as $(7n-6)!$ lol

Comment: I also think that's a beautiful representation of this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac{(7n-6)!}{7^nn!}\implies \log(a_n)=\log((7n-6)!)-n \log(7)-\log(n!)$$

Using Stirling approximation
$$\log(a_n)=6 n (\log (n)-1+\log (7))-\left(6 \log (n)+\frac{11 \log
   (7)}{2}\right)+\frac{29}{14 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Apply it a second time for $a_{n+1}$ and continue with Taylor series
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=6 \log (7 n)-\frac{3}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}=(7n)^6+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: I hate to say it, but I don't know what the Taylor series is yet (I think we'll cover that soon though), and I should've asked the question differently because I represented it wrong with that sum. I am sorry. Thank you for the attempt of help, not your fault I don't understand your answer, or that I messed up the question from the beginning, as saulspatz pointed out.

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins. when you will learn them, just remember me !

Comment: Don't have to tell me twice, I've already started repeating your name out loud to memorize it, then I can tell my professor who introduced me to that!